# Texture painting doesn't work as intended for me

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I've been following Grant Abbitt's Blunderbuss tutorial and have come to a part when he starts painting the mesh after unwrapping it. Now, in his case painting works as intended (streaks register onto the mesh), while in mine everything feels mismatched – the paint doesn't show up on the model or it shows up completely screwed up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the normals are flipped, so you need to go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*:

[image]

Also at the end make sure that you plug your *Principled BSDF* into the *Output*.

Comment: Oh my, thanks, wouldn't even think about that!

You're a life saver!